# Randomly print out precise amount of specific characters

Tags: java

This is my first month learning Java and my first question here, se beaware of newbie mistakses or me omitting something obvious.

I have homework where the program first asks the user to give a number. Then the program would randomly print out that amount of characters from the selection of O (big), o (small) and 0 (zero). So numbers AND letters.

!
So my main problem is how to execute the randomly printing of specific characters using Java?
!

This is my attempt that doesen't do enything even close but decided to post it since the first commentors demanded;

```
    public class ASCIIFISH{
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Hello! How many bubbles is coming from the fish? :-)");
        int kuplat = In.readInt();


        System.out.println( (int) (Math.random(0) * 10) + ">}}}`>");

    }
}
```

edit;
Okay so I got to this point;

```
public class ASCIIFISH{
public static void main(String[] args) {


System.out.println("Moikkelismoi! Kuinka monta kuplaa toivoisit kalan liikehdinnästä syntyvän? :-))");
int kuplat = In.readInt();

 for (int i=0; i<kuplat; i++){
 System.out.print( (int) (Math.random() * 3) );
}

 switch(){

 }

 System.out.println(">}}}`>");

 }
 }
```

Now the program prints out randomly user's amount of 0s,1s and 2s and all I need do still is to change the 1s and 2s to o's and O's. Any ideas?

Okay this did the trick;

```
 public class ASCIIFISH{
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Luetaan käyttäjältä kuplien lukumäärä.
System.out.println("Moikkelismoi! Kuinka monta kuplaa toivoisit kalan liikehdinnästä syntyvän? :-))");
int kuplat = In.readInt();

// Luodaan laskuri joka vertaa itseään käyttäjän antamaan kuplien lukumäärään...
// ...ja muuttuja joka arpoo lukuja väliltä 0-2.
for (int i=0; i<kuplat; i++){
int valinta = ( (int)(Math.random() * 3) );

// Muutetaan tulostuvat (0,1,2) luvut 0,o,O -merkeiksi sekä tulostetaan ne.
if (valinta == 0){
System.out.print("0");
}
else if(valinta == 1){
System.out.print("o");
}
else if(valinta == 2){
System.out.print("O");
}
}

//Tulostetaan itse kala (mahdollisten) kuplien perään.
System.out.println(">}}}`>");
}
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a loop? You have `kuplat` so you want to loop `kuplat` times.

Comment: i want it to print out randomly O's o's and 0's and the 'kuplat' would be the amount of them which the user decides.

Comment: `new Random().ints(n, 0, 3).map(Arrays.asList('O', 'o', '0')::get).forEach(System.out::print);`

Comment: You still need a loop. shmosel uses a stream, which is close, but you should just make a loop. eg. for(int i = 0; i<kuplat; i++){...}

Comment: @matt Why, what's wrong with a stream?

Comment: @shmosel nothing inherently; If this was an actual question about generating random characters, I would think your solution is pretty good.. This is a homework assignment, and I suspect OP should know what a loop is before they know what a stream is.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought you had some issue with my code.

Comment: Assign your value, ie `int choice = (int)(Math.random()*3);` then do you want to switch? Switch on choice. Eg. `switch(choice){ case 0: System.out.print("O"); break; case 1: System.out.print("o"); break;}`

Comment: int arpa = (int)Math.random();
    for (int i=0; i<kuplat; i++){
    System.out.print( (int)(Math.random() * 3) );
    }

    switch(arpa){
    case 1: System.out.print("o");
    break;
    case 2: System.out.print("O");
    break;
    }

Comment: ^^ this doesent do the trick, what am i missing?

Comment: @spacehill you are using `(int)Math.random()` which will always give you 0. You need to use `(int)(Math.random()*3)` which will give you 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Also, you need to have a case 0. Also, your switch should be *inside of your loop*.

Comment: now the program prints out two times the amount of numbers the user gives and they still all 0s, 1,s and 2s

Comment: Can you put your current code in your question now?

Comment: @spacehill I gave an answer which works as far as I can tell - if it's not what you're looking for, let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: I figured it out in a slightly different way (pasted it to my original post), but thanks for everyone anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a random number 1-K, where K is the number of possibilities (3, if I understood correctly), and then use this number and `switch`/`case` to choose which char to print according to the number.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways, but.

```
double d = Math.random();
if(d>0.5){
    System.out.println("a");
} else{
    System.out.println("b");
}
```

That will randomly print out an a, or b.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your desired characters into an array

```
String[] data = new String[]{"o", "0", "O"};
```

Then run a loop over the array based on the user input and print a random one each time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kuplat; i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int num = r.nextInt(data.length);
            System.out.println(data[num]);
        }
```